# ¿Como puedo deshabilitar un boton al crear un registro nuevo?

Tags: php, mysql

, quisiera poder desactivar un boton al crear un nuevo registro si cumple una condicion via php , intente con codigo javascript en php ,pero no lo logre, adjunto imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta en php ya que tengo un buscador en tiempo real en el cual usa codigo php, es para desactivar un boton de descarga, la condicion basicamente indica que si no se sube un archivo que me desactive el boton de descarga ya que no hay archivo que descargar, de antemano Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Aunque hagas un echo del javascript no te sirve de nada si luego cambias de página co un header().  Lo que tienes que haces es dentro de daem_agregar.php comprobar si ese registro ya fue insertado con una consulta SELECT y entonces modificar el botón durante su creación con o sin el atributo disabled

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el código en lugar de usar screenshots. Te sugiero hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que conozcas los lineamientos de la comunidad.

Answer (score 1):

En la parte que dice:

```
document.getElementById("btn-descargar").disabled = true;
```

Tendrías que reemplazar por:

```
document.getElementById("btn-descargar").setAttribute("disabled", true);
```

La API Web setAttribute() es la manera correcta de mandar los valores de los atributos html de forma dinámica, con JavaScript. Su forma de uso sería de la siguiente manera:

```
setAttribute("Nombre del atributo", Valor del atributo)
```

Otra manera, directamente con PHP, podría ser creando una variable y asignarle un valor de acuerdo a tu condición, por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$disabled = "";

$result = mysql_query($con, $sql);

if ($result) {
    $disabled = "disabled";
}

?>

<a href="/link" <?= $disabled ?> >Botón<a>
```

Si tu query se ejecuta de forma correcta, PHP imprimiría la palabra disabled, el cual el documento HTML, lo tomaría como un atributo, ya que estaría dentro de la etiqueta y por ende deshabilitaría el botón.

Al utilizar la sintaxis de:

```
<?= ?>
```

No es necesario escribir echo ya que esta estructura lo hace de por detrás pero, también puedas usar la forma clásica que sería:

```
<?php ?>
```

Pero, allí necesitarías escribirlo de la siguiente forma:

```
<a href="/link" <?php echo $disabled; ?> >Botón<a>
```

Obviamente ya te tocaría personalizar y ajustar un poco esto, de acuerdo a la estructura de tu código.

Comment: Hola!! Gracias por la respuesta, lo intente pero no me produjo el cambio al hacer la insercion :(

Comment: Otra forma de hacerlo directamente con PHP podría ser de creando una variable llamada $disabled = ""; y agregar esa variable a tu botón y si se cumple la condición, el valor de $disabled sería igual a "disabled", es decir $disabled = "disabled", solamente que no te olvides de hacer echo de la variable para que te imprima a la hora de renderizar el html.

Comment: @ChristianAlvarenga esa solución del comentario me parece más adecuada, por favor, inclúyela en tu respuesta también, gracias

Comment: @masterguru listo! Espero que sea de utilidad.

Comment: @ChristianAlvarenga Esperemos que si, que sepa aplicarla, gracias!

Comment: @ChristianAlvarenga no lo decia por la sintaxis del echo, sino más bien por la condición, la cual dependerá primero de saber consultar a la tabla de la base de datos si el registro fue insertado anteriormente en la instrucción INSERT del primer script, y si se cumple entonces entrar en el condicional para agregar el disabled.

Comment: Listo @masterguru, gracias por tu sugerencia, trate de mejorar nuevamente la explicación.

Comment: Hola!! Muchas gracias por sus respuestas! , la idea lo encuentro muy factible , aunque solo me falta poder enviar esta variable a otra vista ,a si que veré como poder enviarlo a otra vista ,si saben como enviar una variable a otra vista sin el form solamente como me habian dicho se agradece !, seguiré buscando!